# How check one cell of tableView and uncheck rest of the cells in the section in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, checkbox

I am working on a project it's like a questionnaire in which I have added three cells in a section containing checkbox. what I want is when I check one checkbox of a cell it should uncheck the rest of the checkboxes of other cells in the same section. I am using checkbox library for check boxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you must create variable called selectedIndex in your vc

```
var selectedIndex: IndexPath!
```

after that in your tableviewcellforrow you must check selectedIndex

```
if self.selectedIndex == nil {
    cell.radioBtn.isselected = false
} else {
    if IndexPath == self.selectedIndex {
        cell.radioBtn.isslected = true
    } else {
        cell.radioBtn.isselected = false
    }
}
```

in your tableview cell after you check radio buttun you must update the selectedIndex

```
self.selectedIndex = indexPath
```

and after that

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```